# Using libssl in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, dylib, libssl

I have tried to include openssl (I try to implement a ssh client) and I've added libssl.dylib to my Xcode Project. But I don't know which header I have to include to use it.
Can anyone show me a tutorial how to use libssl in Xcode?

thanks

Comment: I'm also having this problem.  When I try adding '-lssl' I still get linker errors: `Undefined symbols:
  "_ERR_get_error", referenced from:
      _create_ssl in libpj-i386-apple-darwin10.8.0.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)`

Comment: Oops, my problem was I needed to add both `-lssl` and `-lcrypto`, i.e. **libssl.dylib** and **libcrypto.dylib**

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about OpenSSL regarding includes, it is in the standard SDK and you include the header-files you need from `openssl/*`, e.g.:

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
```